# How can i make inner join in method instead of controller?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have a two tables orders and product. Relation is One to One. In my order class i created method product

```
public function product() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Product', 'key_id', 'key_id');
    }
```

Now in controller i want select rows where id is not null that's why i wanna use InnerJoin

```
Order::where('order_id', 7)
    ->join('products', 'products.key_id', 'orders.key_id')
    ->get();
```

That is fine but i would like get

```
Order::where('order_id', 7)->get();
```

and all join move to method like:

```
public function product() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Product', 'key_id', 'key_id')
     ->join('products', 'products.key_id', 'orders.key_id')
}
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the relations between both the models, so If you fetch order with the following query:

```
Order::where('order_id', 7)->with('product')->get();
```

Remove the join line from product function i.e. `->join('products', 'products.key_id', 'orders.key_id')`

After doing this, dump and die the $order, there will be an key pair with product and its values.